# Ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method '' on a null object reference

Tags: android, массивы

Пытаюсь сделать так,чтобы по нажатию кнопки на 1ом активити из массива выводилась информация на 2ой активити и этот активити сразу открывался,но выходит ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.maxim.myapplicationtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button click;
    Button btnbutton;
    ArrayList<String> test;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        final String[] test = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};


            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        text1.setText(test[1]);
        }


});


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

}}

Шо делать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Одновременно на экране может быть только одна активити. Засим манипулировать разметкой другой активити невозможно напрямую, т.к. она просто не существует.
2. Вы перезатираете слушатели нажатий, засим переход на другую актвити не осуществляется.

Надо так:

1. Запуская активити передавайте в неё через `Intent` данные.
2. В другой актвити данные вытащите и отобразите.